# How can I change the admin menu title and url title on WordPress

Tags: admin-menu

I was hoping someone can help me on how to change the admin menu title and also the link title that goes with it. I want to change Projects admin menu title to Services admin menu. Also, change the link title as well.

Below is the image for your reference.

[image]

Comment: have added  plugin or ceate custom post type ?

Comment: @DharmishthaPatel 

no i have not added anything

Comment: plz check again you have add plugin default wordpress hasnot provide this

Comment: yes, i already installed some plugins for the theme to function properly